# Slow DeterminePostBackMode()

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance

I have performance issue in asp.net page between InitializeCulture and Page_PreInit event. When I override DeterminePostBackMode() I found, that problem is in **base.DeterminePostBackMode();**

Usually takes a few miliseconds, but sometimes (about 5x  per day) it takes very slow (range: few seconds - few minutes).

```
    protected override System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection DeterminePostBackMode()
    {
        // start measure time with log tool

        try
        {
                System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection coll = base.DeterminePostBackMode();
                return coll;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                // log exception with log tool

                throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
                // end measure time with log tool
        }
}
```

I use DevExpress components, IIS 7.5, Internet Explorer 8

Any idea what is wrong? How troubleshoot DeterminePostBackMode() ?

Thanks, Pavel

Comment: does size of returned collection have impact on measured time ?

Comment: I don´t log collection. What do you mean "size"?

Comment: how many items are they in collection ?

Comment: I will try find out. The problem occurs only with our client, so it is hard make quick changes for testing. Thanks for patience.

Comment: Hi. When base.DeterminePostBackMode() is slow, Its return null. But it return null during POST (callback) not GET! So I think it can be the problem ... Problem appears only in IE 8,9. With FireFox everythink works great.

Comment: Sorry no clue, try to debug this method, here are the instructions how to debug into framework source code http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in **httperr log file for HTTP API** this error: **Timer_EntityBody** ... Internet Explorer send header and body separately. So DeterminePostBackMode() wait for body.

I don´t know what is wrong with body, maybe network problems or something else.